# How to pass PointerByReference adress to a structure in JNA

Tags: java, structure, jna, jnaerator

i would have a question regarding the following source, i simplified it to make it a bit easier to understand it.

c code

```
struct test
{
int test1;
};

int create_context(test **context); 
int use_context(test *context);
```

java code

```
public static class test extends Structure {
    public int test1;
    public test() {
        super();
    }
    public test()(Pointer p) {
        super(p);
    }
    protected List getFieldOrder() {
        return Arrays.asList("test1");
    }
    public test(int test1) {
        super();
        this.test1 = test1;
    }
    public static class ByReference extends test implements Structure.ByReference {

    };
    public static class ByValue extends test implements Structure.ByValue {

    };
}
public static native int create_context(PointerByReference context);
public static native int use_context(TestLibrary.test context);
```

I access the structure in java like this,

```
    PointerByReference contextPointer = new PointerByReference();
    int status = INSTANCE.create_context(contextPointer);
    test context = new test(contextPointer.getValue());
    status = INCTANCE.use_context(context);
```

When I debugged this in visual studio, i have seen, that for create_context und use_context different memory adresses are used. 
When i set the the int test1 value, it is right, but I´am wondering, why the adresse of context is different. Does anyone has an Idea? Wouldn´t that led to an memory problem? Or any Idea what I´am doing wrong?
Thanks Valentina

Comment: Are you asking why the value for the variable of type `test **` is different from the variable of type `test *`?

Comment: yes and no :) let´s say, why the adress is different, even i use a the the same pointer. Any Idea?

Comment: Because the value in `test **` is the address of the value in `test *`.

Comment: You should also call `Structure.read()` in your `test(Pointer)` ctor.

Comment: okay, thanks for help. I tried it with your suggestion, but still the same. With further investigation, i have seen, that the     test context = new test(contextPointer.getValue()); already passes the new adress. When i use contextPointer.getPointer() it uses the right one, but an "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Structure exceeds provided memory bounds
 at com.sun.jna.Structure.useMemory(Structure.java:304)
 at com.sun.jna.Structure.useMemory(Structure.java:282)" occurs

Comment: I think you need to clarify your question.  `contextPointer.getPointer()` gives you the address of a pointer (4 or 8 bytes), which presumably your native code filled in with the address of a block of memory sufficiently large for your `struct`.  Be more explicit in your question about *all* the details of both your native *and* Java code, because apparently your native code is not doing what you say it is doing.

Comment: Okay, you are right. So, it might be important that i post the code of create_context          *context = (test*) malloc( sizeof( test ) );
    memset( *context, 0, sizeof( test ) ); Thats maybe the Reason why jna is not able to calculate the allocated memory and throws the error, when using getPointer, or what would you think? In case this could be reason, any idea how to fix it? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You hav chosen the convention of generally using `struct test*`, so we'll work with that.

Your native code needs to look like this:

```
int create_context(struct test **context) {
    *context = (struct test *)malloc(sizeof(test));
    // initialize here...
    return 0;
}
```

When you call `create_context`, you must pass in *the address* of a pointer:

```
struct test* test_ptr;

create_context(&test_ptr);

test_ptr->some_field = ...; // operate on your struct via pointer
```

It's important to keep straight when you're using the structure by value (`struct test`), by reference (`struct test*`), or the address of your reference (`struct test**`).  Whether your usage is in C or in Java, the concepts are the same.